# How to manually transfer entire Whatsapp installation to another device (the hard way)

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, android-x86

I'm using Whatsapp from a virtual machine since I lost my phone, and now need to transfer it to a new VM.

The easy way would be to use the backup feature native to Whatsapp, but it is disabled since the VM is connected via Ethernet (and Android thinks it's a Mobile connection). In fact the very "local backup" feature is not available. I have a ton of messages which I really wouldn't like to lose.

There's an Xposed module which could possible fake an Wifi connection in the Android VM, but at this point I really want to do the entire transfer locally as my internet is painfully slow right now.

I tried the built-in `adb backup` feature, only to find out it's disabled for Whatsapp and can't be easily enabled (requires decompiling the `apk` file).

So, how can I manually transfer Whatspp app data to the new "device"? What folders do I need to copy, and what files must be modified in order for the transfer to work seamlessly?

I do of course have full root access.

**[Update]** Neither of the following work:

- Copying the entire contents of `/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases` after installing Whatsapp, signing in and closing it. It will crash when opening, without any error message.
- Copying the same directory, but without opening Whatsapp and signing in after installation. Same error as above.
- Copying `/data/data/com/whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db` after installing Whatsapp and signing in. An error message is presented: "Something went wrong with your chat history"
- Copying the entire `/data/data/com.whatsapp` directory, after installing and closing it. It will crash when opening, without any error message.

Comment: The concept would be to create a **TAR** archive of anything under **/data/data/com.whatsapp** (in order to preserve the permissions and ownerships). Then, you'll need to install WhatsApp on the new host machine, and lastly you should untar the previously created archive under the **/data/data/com.whatsapp** directory of the new machine, overwriting all of the files that'll be already there. This should emulate the backup operation performed by a dedicated app, but remembered that this is a mere concept I didn't test yet.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I did try, unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. The app will crash when I try to open it.

Comment: Don't you have root? If you do, you could use some application like Titanium Backup.

It's been a while since I last used Android, but copying apps, especially Whatsapp, will hardly work for apps such as Whatsapp, Facebook or Messenger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was encountering the crashing behaviour trying these approaches too, but @DeathMaskSalesman seems to've been on the right track—the crashes are indeed a permissions issue.

If you remove WhatsApp entirely, reinstall it, and copy `/data/data/com.whatsapp` over and adjust the permissions correctly *before* launching it the first time, then it should just need to reverify your number to work.  This worked for me.

To adjust permissions, first use `ls -la` to check the permissions on what's put in the `/data/data/com.whatsapp` directory upon install, e.g.:

```
drwxrwx--x   3 u0_a105 u0_a105  4096 2018-07-14 00:55 cache
```

Then use the username and group (here both `u0_a105`) to rename the files after you've copied them in:

```
chown -R u0_a105:u0_a105 /data/data/com.whatsapp/*
```

Then WhatsApp should launch okay without crashes, and retain settings, messages, and multimedia.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this the next time. Makes sense and should work, I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: @Brune, this sounds like something worth asking as a separate question.

Comment: This works perfectly! When I only move the data the app crashes if the devices has different users/groups names from original device. But after I set the username and group it works, thanks @JonathanW.

Answer (score 4):

If you have root, you can use TitaniumBackup to save Whatsapp data.

If you don't have root, you can downgrade to Whatsapp 2.11.431 (you can find it [here](https://www.androidfreeapks.com/it/apk/whatsapp-messenger-2-11-431-apk/)) which was the latest version with `adb backup` feature activated, and then proceed backing up with adb ([instructions](https://stackpointer.io/mobile/android-adb-backup-extract-restore-repack/372/)).

Comment: It's been quite a few years since this answer - can anyone confirm if the downgrade still works without corrupting data?

Answer (score 2):

THX to this [guide here from xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/whatsapp-restore-encrypted-backup-t3462246) I was handle to perform a manually transfer of my entire Whatsapp conversations (120000 messages :D).

Simple:

1. Make a full TWRP Backup of your old rom if possible +pull it with adb or MTP from your phone
2. Copy with TWRP Terminal, TWRP Filemamanger, ADB or with your running system with root access this file: /data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key
3. Check the filesize of that key-file. It should be 158 Bytes. If there are multiple, choose them all. But later you need the one with 158 Bytes.
4. Copy the key file and the Folder /sdcard/Whatsapp to your local-machine.
5. On your new phone: Install Whatsapp and open it but do nothing more. Let it open and hold the power-button to shutdown or restart into your TWRP recovery.
6. Within TWRP push "**W**hatsapp" folder with all it's content to your /sdcard/ folder and psuh the key file (that one with 158 Bytes) into /data/data/com.whatsapp/files/
7. Start your new phone again and start Whatsapp. Press restore, if you got the message that it does not found anything in "/sdcard/Whatsapp/backup", go ahead and verify your number. In my case WA found the database then and restored my 120000 messages.

If I understand that right:

- /data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key
  Is the encrypton key for your database with all your messages.
- /sdcard/Whatsapp/Databases/msgstore.db.crypt12
  Should be your database with all your messages in it. There could be some more with a date in the filename. These should be smaller and older then the msgstore.db.crypt12.
- /sdcard/Whatsapp/Media
  Contains media :-P
  If you lost this, only the messages would be there and the media had just nothing to link to it.

I am happy now. I was able to switch from Android 7 (LineageOS) to Android 8.1 (CarbonRom) without using Google-Apps anymore. So no Backup from the cloud would be needed. MicroG has a [bug](https://github.com/microg/android_packages_apps_GmsCore/issues/547) with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find WhatsApp data in the directory `/data/data/com.whatsapp`, just copy all the contents of subdirectory `databases` with `adb pull /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases` and transfer it onto your new VM with `adb push path/to/saved/databases/directory /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases`, be sure the target it's empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm guessing I must first install Whatsapp on the new VM, right? Or should I create the `/com.whatsapp/databases` manually as the first step?

Comment: Yes, you must install WhatsApp, then register your account as usual, that will create the `com.whatsapp` folder and its contents.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I get the following message when attempting to open Whatsapp: "Something went wrong with your chat history".

Comment: There is any difference between WhatsApp versions in both VMs?

Comment: No, it's the same version.

Comment: Ouch. Something did go wrong. It worked previously, don't know why but I just tried that on my account and I had the same result. I'm sorry :/

Comment: Altough I don't think it could work, as it's like copying the entire `com.whatsapp` folder: I had another idea. Try copying (very carefully, do backup of both "key" files) `/data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key` to your target VM at the same location, and then try the procedure in the answer. (I can't test this because I have not a backup key, but it's a theory)

Answer (score 0):

I used to backup only the  `msgstore.db`  file located in `/data/data/com.whatsapp/files` before uninstalling, and copying it to the same folder after new installation. But this doesn't seem to work anymore since version 2.19.xx.

From the comments, I think `key` file is the new factor here. Will try.

Comment: Was the key file the new factor? I also used to backup msgstore.db but then realized it had become insufficient. Now I'm not sure what to backup to avoid saving the whole com.whatsapp folder