# Salvage app cache when unable to open app

Tags: applications, adb, backup, whatsapp-messenger, cache

Every time my phone reboots and sometimes even without reboot when it's working at I guess full capacity, it resets its settings and acts like I just booted the phone for the first time except from all the apps I've installed (i.e. non system apps) still being installed. However, I cannot open any non-preinstalled app as they just close immediately when I open them. Deleting the cache and/or force stopping the app doesn't help.

Since my last WhatsApp backup file *msgstore.db.crypt12* is a couple days old, I tried to "rescue" the WhatsApp cache since the msgstore.db is just a backup file and WhatsApp stores the messages "live" in a different database that doesn't seem to be accessible without root (and I cannot root my phone at the moment).

The WhatsApp app-info shows that WhatsApp actually still occupies a lot of cache data and app data and the WhatsApp symbol on my application overview still shows the number of unread messages I had before the last unwanted reset.

I already tried backing up the whole app with as much app data as possible via adb with *adb backup C:\wabackup.ab -apk -obb -shared com.whatsapp*, uninstalling WhatsApp, reinstalling it and then restoring the backup but running the app afterwards just prompts me with the screen I would usually get when running the app for the first time after the installation.

The WhatsApp folder seems to be totally fine but maybe it's a permission issue with the folder. ( [How to manually transfer entire Whatsapp installation to another device (the hard way)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/150071/how-to-manually-transfer-entire-whatsapp-installation-to-another-device-the-har) )

I would really like to fix this, not only for WhatsApp but also for other more important apps like banking-apps and 2-factor-authentication-apps that of course encounter the same problem at the moment but unfortunately I am not too familiar with the way Android stores app data.

This is pretty annoying obviously and I have already ordered a new phone. I am currently using the SM-J510FN.

Comment: Take a moment and make question shorter, nobody is going to read this much text, trust me. Since you are mentioning cache, I don't think that is where backups are stored, since it easily can be deleted. Don't WhatsApp have online backups?

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Fair point, gonna shorten the question in a couple minutes. Yes, WhatsApp supports online backups but this feature just regularly uploads the most recent msgstore.db.crypt12 into the cloud and since this file is too old, restoring from the cloud doesn't fix the problem in my case